# Insert element into struct vector

Tags: c++, struct

I want to initialize a struct using a function and also insert into it as seen below.  I want to initialize the array dynamically I want to declare two struct vectors, one dynamically and the other statically

Comment: If this is C++ why the procedural functions instead of adding functions to `vector`? Define `vector::vector()` instead of this non-standard `initialize` function. It's also an opportunity to learn about destructors, which are mandatory if you allocate with `new`.

Comment: Hint: `vec.array[size];` doesn't allocate, it just exercises an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Why do you have a max_size in vector if you aren't checking that condition when you insert an element?

Answer (score 2):

Your `initialize()` function is not allocating any memory for the array, and it is also not initializing the `current_size` to the correct value. It needs to look like this instead:

```
void initialize(vector &vec, int size){
    vec.current_size = 0;
    vec.array = new int[size];
    vec.max_size = size;
}
```

And then you need a function to free the array when you are done using it, eg:

```
void finalize(vector &vec){
    delete[] vec.array;
    vec.current_size = 0;
    vec.max_size = 0;
}
```

Also, your `insert()` function should be updated to avoid a buffer overflow once the array fills up to its max capacity:

```
void insert( vector &vec, int element){
    if (vec.current_size < vec.max_size){
        vec.array[vec.current_size] = element;
        vec.current_size++;
    }
}
```

If needed, this would also allow you to grow the array instead:

```
void insert( vector &vec, int element){
    if (vec.current_size == vec.max_size){
        int new_max = vec.max_size * 2;
        int *new_array = new int[new_max];
        for(int i = 0; i < vec.current_size; ++i){
            new_array[i] = vec.array[i];
        }
        delete[] vec.array;
        vec.array = new_array;
        vec.max_size = new_max;
    }
    vec.array[vec.current_size] = element;
    vec.current_size++;
}
```